# Use ffmpeg to add audio in the middle of the video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a 9s no-audio mp4 video and a 5s mp3 audio. And now I want to add the mp3 in the middle in the video. I totally have no idea how I can do that.

I tried

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[2:a]asplit[dum1][dum2];[dum1][0:v][1:a][dum2]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[v][a];" -map [v] -map [a] -y output.mp4
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[2:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a0];[a0]apad[a]" -map 0:v -map [a] -shortest -y output.mp4
```

The changes from the OP's command is that only a new audio stream is generated via `concat` instead of both video and audio. First filter prepends the 2nd (silent) audio to the MP3, then the apad appends that result with silence of infinite length.  But the shortest flag stops the encoding when the video stream is fully processed.

Comment: This might be a good solution to the asker, but it will not help other people much. Can you elaborate a bit. E.g. We do this and this and these switches/options are used for that.